# Change Text in TH with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a stock market plugin that show me the current stock values.
Now i wwant to make the website Multi Language and tried to use javascript for the change (static).

```
<table>
<thead>
  <tr>
          <th>Symbol</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th class="smw-tablesort smw-Decimal">Aktueller Marktwert</th>
          <th class="smw-tablesort smw-Decimal">Änderung</th>
          <th class="smw-tablesort smw-Percent">Änderung in %</th>
        </tr>
</thead>
<tbody></table>
```

i tried the following code:

```
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace('Name', 'Start');
```

But it doesnt work

The data from the plugin come with a env.joson file. So they are text strings. I just can translate in one language but I need 3 languages.

Comment: There are plenty of libraries out there that help with i18n support. The way you are doing it now will be very error prone and a pain to maintain.

Comment: You could always keep it simple and use Google's Translator widget also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just based on the code we can see in your post.

```
document.querySelectorAll('th')[1].style.color = "blue";
```

I'm finding the 2nd TH tag and setting the color that way. You can set values that way also.

```
document.querySelectorAll('th')[1].innerText = "start";
or 
document.querySelectorAll('th')[1].innerHTML = "start";
```

Comment: That was very helpful! Thank you. The solution: <script type="text/javascript"> 



</script>


<script type ="text/javascript">
window.onload = function what(){
document.querySelectorAll('th')[0].innerHTML = "Ikon";
};
</script>